# Force download of same named artifact from alternative Nexus repository

Tags: maven, dependencies, nexus

I have a problem with a Maven artifact from a predecessor.
He modified an external maven library and uploaded it under the same version name to the Nexus releases repo.
When I build my project I obviously get the official version and not the intended.
Locally I just overwrite my local .m2 repo with it.
But for our cicd server this is not an outcome, because I have no file system access, and because the situation might repeat itself.
There is no source code so rebuilding and reversioning would be cumbersome.

My question is: how can I force to get the artifact downloaded from the releases and not the default central repo, meanwhile getting all other dependencies come from the latter?

Comment: You don't need the source code to change the version of an artifact. If you have the right to upload to Nexus, you can just download the artifact, change the version in the `pom.xml` (to maybe `1.2.3-patched`) and then upload it again. This would be the cleanest solution of the mess.

Comment: Thank you Fabian, I will give it a try. Hopefully no conflicts with transient deps.

Comment: Worked like a charm Fabian, only had to hash manually files to md5 and sha1.